# Use "K" on a custom language

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

We know that pressing 'K' will trigger the manual page for the underlying language. I am writing a syntax file for a language, and the document is online only. So I would like to know

1. How do I react to 'K'?
2. How do I, rather than calling "man" on that keyword, pop up a new browser window and open the given page?

Thanks!

Comment: Behaviour belongs in a filetype plugin, not a syntax file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>K</kbd> runs the program given by `keywordprg` (kp).

If you do `:set keywordprg?` it should reply `keywordprg=man` by default.

So simply set `keywordprg` to a program of choice, which will get the language name as input. Check if the language is the one you want and fire it up in the browser, otherwise call `man` on the input as usual.

`:help K` tells you this and more